# Jasper pdfFontName Exception

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm developing a reports feature which exports data to XLS, DOC and PDF using Jasper and Java.

For some reason I cant export to PDF while using Hebrew, I keep getting this error :

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font : 
pdfFontName   : Times-Roman
pdfEncoding   : Identity-H
isPdfEmbedded : false
```

I've tried to embed the font in the report using Jasper Studio and added the Jasper Fonts jar and configured the font there as well.

Any ideas how to solve this one?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never worked with Hebrew but whenever I am having trouble with Cyrillic fonts I switch to *Arial* and it usually does the trick.

Comment: So I need to change the report fields ?
The problem is, even if I change the report fonts and it will work, it might happen again because the reports are not mine, I just populate the data.

Any other ideas?

Comment: No, just replace all fonts with Arial - works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Install the Fonts as usual.
I got this error on my server, then I just found that TTF file and install it.
If Jasper studio is giving the error, you can install the missing font too.

2. Quick Fix is to change all the fonts with Arial other fonts which is working for you (Arial is common font available on all machine or you can use SansSerif).

SansSerif is the default font which i use before installing font